# What do 0x0040 and pipe sign denote here?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Here SIMPLE_EX2 is being ORed with 0x0040 and the whole this providing as an address to SIMPLE_EX1. Is my understanding correct?

```
#define SIMPLE_EX1  (0x0040 | SIMPLE_EX2)
```

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.As I understand *"providing as an address"* is not what you really meant to say but ended up making it sound like you do.

Comment: Except for the word "address" you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` is not a pipe sign in C. It's a bit-wise or. So this expression:

```
0x0040 | SIMPLE_EX2
```

Simply gets the value of `SIMPLE_EX2` and sets it's 7<sup>th</sup> bit (from right) to 1.

---

Unlikely, but note that if `SIMPLE_EX2` itself is an expression with an operator that has lower precedence than `|`, the overall expression may be interpreted wrongly. For example if `SIMPLE_EX2` is `a?b:c`, then `SIMPLE_EX1` becomes `(0x0040|a)?b:c` which is not what I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

You should read a good C programming book (if you are learning C), or a good C++ programming book if you are learning C++.

Assuming `SIMPLE_EX2` is `#define`-d as a constant integer, or a constant integer expression in parenthesis, then `SIMPLE_EX1`is that integer bit-or-ed with the `0x0040` hexadecimal constant (ie 64 in decimal, or 0b1000000 in binary).

Comment: It doesn't have to be constant. Whatever integer expression `SIMPLE_EX2` expands to, the result gets the 7-th bit set to 1.

Comment: Agreed, but the original poster did not gave any context for his question. And if `SIMPLE_EX2` is not defined, or ill-defined (e.g. as a string, or the name of a variable undefined at some using occurrence of `SIMPLE_EX1`) the question does not make sense. So I had to guess what `SIMPLE_EX2` might be.

Answer (score 2):

> SIMPLE_EX2 is being ORed with 0x0040

yes.

> and the whole this providing as an address to SIMPLE_EX1.

no.

The #define preprocessor directive is basically a find-and-replace text operation which is done before compilation. Nothing more and noting less. So whenever you write `SIMPLE_EX1` in your code, it is textually replaced with `(0x0040 | SIMPLE_EX2)` before compilation.

Interesting code snippet which illustrates this:

```
#define SIX 1+5
#define NINE 8+1

printf("Six times nine is %d.", SIX * NINE);
```

This code will return 42, not 54 like one would expect, because the preprocessor turns the whole program into:

```
printf("Six times nine is %d.", 1 + 5 * 8 + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just setting the 7th bit from right for `SIMPLE_EX2` and assigning it to `SIMPLE_EX1`