# Using #define macros in a simple cout expression

Tags: c++

I would like to ask why this code prints out 2 instead of 0. Doesn't `#define` "assign" values to the names of the macros and calculate also the result? How does it give this answer?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define A    0
#define B    A+1
#define C    1-B

int main() {
    cout << C<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C -> "1-B" -> "1-A+1" -> "1-0+1" = 2

Comment: doesn't go like 1-(0+1)

Comment: You would have to add the parenthesis into the macros.

Comment: A=0;B=0+1-->B=1 ;C=1-B-->C=1-1

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't calculate anything. It's a simple text replacement.

Comment: I like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12278121/4975646) which illustrates how SIX (`#define SIX 1+5`) times NINE (`#define NINE 8+1`) equals 42.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are direct text replacements  That means

```
#define C    1-B
```

becomes

```
1-A+1
```

and then A gets expanded so we have

```
1-0+1
```

which is 2.  If you want 0 then stop using macros and instead use constant variables

```
const int A = 0;
const int B = A + 1;
const int C = 1 - B;
```

And now C is 0.

Comment: One can also use parenthesis in macros to enforce precedence.

Comment: @lisyarus True.  I am not a big have of #defines and in a case like this I would use a const variable instead of them.

Comment: Thank you in general i am avoiding calculation in macros, but i was playing aroundand i found that i am missing something.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree. Just mentioned that for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor expands the `C` macro to `1-B`, which expands to `1-A+1` which expands to `1-0+1` which equals `2`. Don't think of it in terms of sequential assignment, but you can get the desired behavior by adding parenthesis around the macro definitions. Then the `C` macro would expand to `(1-B)`, then `(1-(A+1))` then `(1-((0)+1))` which equals `0`.

*Edit:*

As an example, the code snip below prints `42`, even though `BAR` is "assigned" to `FOO` when `FOO` equals `17`. This is because the expansion is deferred until it's actually used. On the `cout` line, `BAR` is still equal to `FOO`, but at that point, `FOO` is now `42`, not `17`. Note that it's bad practice to redefine a macro without first `#undef`ining it.

```
#define FOO 17
#define BAR FOO
#define FOO 42
cout << BAR << endl;
```

Comment: I thought that it calculates A then B then C.

Comment: @kyrpav The preprocessor doesn't *calculate* anything. Rather it saves the macro name and its associated expansion.  Only at run-time (or probably compile-time in this case) is the arithmetic performed. I've updated the answer to hopefully make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `C` expands to `1-0+1`

Preprocessor defines simply replace text and don't care about operator precedence or calculation rules.